# How to Compare two IEnumerable Collections using LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm

I am using a WPF application with MVVM model. I want to know how to compare
 two IEnumerable collection values. I am having **two IEnumerable** values , named as 
 **AvailablePacks** and **RecommendedPacks**. These two collection have different set of values but they are having common property **PackID** value. And AvailablePacks having a another property named as **Quantity**.

Now i want to compare these two IEnumerable collection values **based upon PackID** value, When the both collection having the same **PackID** I need to assign that **Quantity**(Inside of AvailablePacks) value to some variable called **PackQuantity** Which is declared outside .

I am new to LINQ So i am not able to do this properly.

So How Can i achieve this? Can any one tell me a solution of this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - particularly when it comes to things like "PackQuantity which is declared outside" - declared outside what?

Comment: The question is not clear - how can a collection have a single `PackID` value?

Comment: Its declared outside of the method .Which is not present in Both the Collection

Comment: @SuryaKavitha: *Where* is it declared though? In another type? What type? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - the clearer your question is, the better the answers are likely to be.

Comment: @jon : Its an int type property

Comment: @SuryaKavitha: Property of which type? Again, your question is *still* unclear. You've accepted an answer which uses an anonymous type... is that what you really wanted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  var result = from ap in AvailablePacks  
             join rp in RecommendedPacks 
               on ap.PackID equals rp.PackID
               select new {
                  PackQuantity = ap.Quantity
               };
```

Comment: how do we this using LamdaExpression?

Comment: @SuryaKavitha did you Say LambdaExpression. `var result=`AvailablePacks.Join(RecommendedPacks , ap => ap.PackID,rp => rp.PackID,(ap, rp) => new{PackQuantity = ap.Quantity});

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var query = from x in AvaillablePacks
            join y in RecommendedPacks on x.PackID equals y.PackID
            select new
            {
                PackQuantity = x.Quantity
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Somethign like this *should* work for you:

```
var result = (from availablePack in AvaillablePacks 
                join recommendedPack in RecommendedPackson 
                     availablePack.PackID equals recommendedPack .ID)

foreach(var availablePack in result)
    availablePack .Quantity = PackQuantity ;
```